# Custom Middleware in sail.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

In my Sails app, I want to access to a static folder which is not in "assets".

In express, I could do this easily by setting for example :

> app.use('/static_path', express.static(__dirname +
>   '/views/static_path'));

So in Sails, I try to add a Middleware in "config/http.js".

Here is my issue. When I add the custom Middleware :

> customMiddleware: function(app){
>       var express = require('../node_modules/sails/node_modules/express');
>
> ```
> app.use('/static_path', express.static(__dirname + '/../views/static_path'));   }
> ```

1. According to the documentation, I should be able to access to "CustomMiddleware" by passing $custom into "order" (which is listing all middlewares). But the middleware is never called by this way
2. Actually in the "order" list, if I add in word "customMiddleware", it works. But the second point is that app is crashing and log

> app.use is not a function

Could someone help me ? Sorry For my English by the way

Comment: So, did @hlozancic answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to require express before you use app.use.

Try something like this:

config/http.js

```
var express = require('express'); // if you have npm version > 2
// var express  = require('sails/node_modules/express'); // for older npm versions

module.exports.http = {

customMiddleware: function (app) {
    app.use('/static_path', express.static(__dirname + '/../views/static_path'));
},   ... rest of the http.js
```